# Fast exchange of data between unmanaged code and managed code

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Without using p/invoke, from a C++/CLI I have succeeded in integrating various methods of a DLL library from a third party built in C.

One of these methods retrieves information from a database and stores it in different structures. The C++/CLI program I wrote reads those structures and stores them in a List<>, which is then returned to the corresponding reading and use of an application programmed completely in C#. I understand that the double handling of data (first, filling in several structures and then, filling all of these structures into a list<>) may generate an unnecessary overload, at which point I wish C++/CLI had the keyword "yield".

Depending on the above scenario, do you have recommendations to avoid or reduce this overload?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the `yield` keyword to create iterators. Just create one class implementing `IEnumerator<T>` and another class implementing `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, do you know about a web site for getting some examples?

Comment: Here's one I found from Googling: http://www.brianensink.com/blog/post/Implementing-IEnumerable3cT3e-in-C2b2bCLI.aspx